# How to know USIM card PIN code status (enabled or disabled)

Tags: lte, umts

I'm writing a USIM driver and I want to know if I can know the status of the PIN code of the USIM whether it is enabled or disabled. I wrote commands to enable, disable, verify, unblock and change PIN code but I can't find a way to write a function that checks the status.
When I read IMSI file during PIN code is enabled I got "Security conditions not satisfied" and the PIN code is not provided then I can conclude that it is enabled but I want a neat, simple and more direct method

Answer (score 0):

102 221 Section 9.5.2 PIN status indication

In the FCP response, look for C6 09 90 01. The byte after that is a bit array of flags for each PIN.